# Spring integration : Get messages in channel as List

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to subscribe to a PubSub channel, to get all messages payload and processing them.

The thing is, I saw example with `IntegrationFlow`, but if I understand this correctly, integrationFlow is used to get from a channel, and send to another one.

I don't want to send to another channel, I just want to get the payload, to process it.

How can I do this?

All examples I found use xml files to make the configuration, but the project was not created using this way of doing.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw example with IntegrationFlow, but if I understand this correctly, integrationFlow is used to get from a channel, and send to another one.

I think that this is not correct information. You can just handle the messages.
You can do something like this in a configuration class:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows.from(...)
    .handle((GenericHandler<YourMessage>) (message, headers) -> {...})
}
```

Comment: There are really no need to link the IntegrationFlows to an OutputChannel?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Try to implement it from the example I posted in the answer.

Comment: The answer is correct, but you need to change logic to the `handle(MessageHandler)` which is really one-way endpoint and is not going to return anything to make you to add that `channel()` in the end. @MrNierda, you probably mixing an `IntegrationFlow` abstraction with an `endpoint` which are slightly different in their goals. Although an `IntegrationFlow` is really can play an endpoint role in the streaming logic. See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl